# How to display the array index value at console in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I display array index value in console window on click of the button which is present inside the carousel component? where the console window is displaying index value twice  and at last its redirecting to 1st array index value as 1.
Console window should only display the index value with increment of 1 so it starts displaying array index value from.

### guide.html

```html
<tr *ngFor="let guide of guides">
  <td>{{guide.Type}}</td>
  <td>{{guide.PageColor}}</td>
  <td>
   <carousel class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
     <slide  *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index ">
       <p>Image: {{i+1}}</p>
       <img src="{{image.image}}" alt="First slide"/>
       <p (click)="idValue(i)">
         <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
         <label for="file">{{image.change}}</label>
       </p>
      </slide>
   </carousel>
 </td>
</tr>
```

### guide.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
@Component({
  templateUrl: './guide.html'
})
export class GuideComponent {
 guides : any = [{ Type: 'Company', PageColor: 'red'},{ Type: 'Company', PageColor: 'Blue'}];

 images:any = [{image :'img1.jpg', change:'change'},{image: 'img2.jpg', change:'add'},{image:'img3.jpg', change:'edit'},{image:'im4.jpg',change:'delete' }];
        
 idValue(i) {
  i=i+1;
  console.log(i);
 }
}
```

Comment: can u please rephrase the question a bit ? i think i might understood what is the problem but i don't want to post an answer before i am certain. thanks

Comment: console is printing the index value, everytime it is printed twice and it is always printing 1 at 2nd time

Comment: so how to avoid it printing 1 in console, if index value is 3 its displaying 3 1st and along with 3 its displaying 1

Comment: It can be that the carousel **$event** is triggered twice try in html: `<p (click)="$event, idValue(i)">` in in component: `idValue(event, i) {
  i=i+1;
  console.log(event, i);
 }` and check the output.

Comment: No its not working with event thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code, that works.
In two words = simple types (number is our case) copied to click-handler arguments, not send by ref. So every time you got same value from i.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div  *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index ">
          <p>Image: {{i+1}}</p>

          <p (click)="idValue(i)">
          Button
          </p>
         </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  { 

  images:any = [{image :'img1.jpg', change:'change'},{image: 'img2.jpg', change:'add'},{image:'img3.jpg', change:'edit'},{image:'im4.jpg',change:'delete' }];
  indexArr = new Array(this.images.length + 1);

    idValue(i) {
      if(!this.indexArr[i]) { this.indexArr[i] = 0};
        this.indexArr[i] += 1;
        console.log('index:', i, ' Click number', this.indexArr[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying but its not displaying any index value in console

Comment: Corrected to display index and clicknumber